# Finding initial value to get a convergent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Assume that a sequence of real number $\begin{Bmatrix}
{S}_{n}\end{Bmatrix}$ satisfes: ${S}_{1}=b;\quad {S}_{n+1}={S}^{2}_{n}+\left(1-2a \right){S}_{n}+{a}^{2}(n\in  \mathbb{N});\quad a,b\in \mathbb{R}.$

Finding the relationship between a and b, show that $\begin{Bmatrix}
{S}_{n}\end{Bmatrix}$ converges in $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: suppose $S_{n+1} =S_n$ and see what you get as conditions

Answer (score 2):

We have $$S_{n+1}=\left(S_n-a\right)^2+S_n \ge S_n$$ for all $ n \ge 1$. Hence the $\{S_n\}$ is monotonically increasing. Moreover if it converges, then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n=a$$. Therefore if $ b \gt a$, then the given sequence diverges. In the case $$a-1 \le b \le a$$, we have also $$a-1 \le S_n \le a$$ for $ n \gt 1$. Thus for such $b$ the sequence converges. Finally if $ b \lt a-1$, then $ S_2 \gt a$ and consequently the sequence diverges.